# Faster way to remove spikes from enemies?

Tags: the-wonderful-101

I'm on 003-A and I'm wondering if there is any way to remove spikes from enemies faster than just whacking away at them with the whip.  I usually draw big shapes so that Wonder Pink is on fire (whatever that is called) and that usually makes pieces come off every 3rd or 4th time I connect, but it doesn't last very long and it takes up a ton of battery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I've seen, that's the only way to get things done faster: use a bigger Unite Morph. However, if your whip is still jumbo-sized when the armor comes off, you might notice that it removes more than one piece at a time. If you're struggling to make your larger Morph last long enough, try striking the enemy a few times with a smaller whip to soften it up, then deliver the *coup de grace* with a larger one to give yourself some room for error.

You might also try separating your team to make multiple Unite Whips and strike the enemy from multiple angles at once to speed things up a touch. Just draw the whip's shape with a Wonder-Liner and then press X to have one of your teammates use the Unite Whip independently. This still costs Energy, though, so keep an eye on your gauge to make sure you have enough for further attacks.